# Confusion with * in Sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have this file:

```
test.txt
============
a b c
testing=123
a b c
```

I thought the following command will replace the testing=123 line.

```
sed "s/^testing=*/testing=alpha/g" test.txt
```

It is resulting into:

```
a b c
testing=alpha123
a b c
```

So I need:

```
sed "s/^testing=[^\n]*/testing=alpha/g" test.txt
```

to get this:

```
a b c
testing=alpha
a b c
```

Can anyone explain what is happening. The * there should match all the characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` means any number of repetitions of the previous construct (including 0 repetitions). `.` means any character. So you should have `.*` for matching all the characters, not `*` (which is from globbing).

So, this is the solution:

```
$ sed "s/^testing=.*/testing=alpha/g"  test.txt
a b c
testing=alpha
a b c
```

Comment: You were fast! I delete my answer as yours was first and explains it better :) +1

Comment: Now I know how [^\n]* was working. It was matching up any characters other than a new line char.

Comment: Just pointing out for completeness, "any number of repetitions" includes zero repetitions.  `*` matches zero or more occurrences of the previous construct.

Answer (score -1):

This does not explain `sed`, but shows how it could be done with `awk`

```
awk -F= '/^testing/ {$2="alpha"}1' OFS== test.txt
```